# Angular Material Input template based type validation

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I'm using an Angular Material  and although the documentation says that the HTML5 type attribute should be interpreted as a validator directive, it's not seeing it as such and no validation errors are raised when the field's value doesn't match the type. For example: URL.

Tried the following:

```
<input name="urlInput" [(ngModel)]="profile.url" matInput type="url">
```

Comment: I had a similar question when using the email type. Stackblitz demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v2z7fx?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an open issue with Angular template driven forms. See open bug here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16352